# How to find Web Parts on the current page using SP.js

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-part-page

I am trying to find out the title of the current page with SP.js without having to get it from the DOM.

Is there a way to find what Web Parts are on the current page?

Comment: This seems to be two different questions in one? If so, please divide it into two questions.

Answer (score 3):

You have two ways:

1. Use the `GetLimitedWebPartManager` that give to you access on what web part you have on the current page.
2. You can use JQuery to find all the div tag that using one of the following css class: ms-WPBody, also ms-webpart-*, and also the webpart's id start with a "WebPartWP*"

Do some crawling on your DOM and you will find what do you need.

To get the current page title the only way to do that is reading the DOM.
That means:

1) by JQuery: `var current_title = $(document).attr('title');`
2) standard JS: `document.title`

Comment: This doesn't do what I was hoping it would, I am trying to get the current page title without crawling the DOM

Comment: Ok but I read two questions: get document title and get all the current web parts on the page